Standard deviation has two different values?
It is known that 56 % of Infiglow batteries have a life of less than 16 hours, and 94 % have a life less than 17 hours. It can be assumed that battery life is modelled by the normal distribution $N(μ,σ^2)$.
a. Find the value of $μ$ and the value of $σ$.
The problem is solved by using two simultaneous equations of
$$ \frac{16−μ}{σ} = 0.1509 $$
and
$$ \frac{17−μ}{σ} = 1.554. $$
I solved for the correct mean of 15.9, but I found that the standard deviation has two possible solutions depending on which z score formula I use. If I substitute $μ = 15.9$ into $\frac{16−μ}{σ} = 0.1509$ I get $σ = 0.663$. If I substitute $μ = 15.9$ into $\frac{17−μ}{σ} = 1.554$ I get $σ = 0.712$, which is the correct answer. Why does $σ$ have two possible values? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

@AnotherUser I fixed the formatting so that it no longer requires an image.

To your question, I don't understand what you are proposing.  The given data tells us that $\frac {16-\mu}{\sigma}=.1509$ and that $\frac {17-\mu}{\sigma}=1.554$  That's two equations in two unknowns, linear after you cross multiply by $\sigma$.  Just solve for $\mu, \sigma$.

@lulu I understand that. The problem is with solving for σ gives two different answers depending on which data point is used to find it.

A quick read suggests the error might be writing $a - b/c$ instead of $(a-b)/c$.

That doesn't make sense.  These equations are not dependent, they have a unique solution.  Here

@EthanBolker That's also not the case. Otherwise I would get values of σ = -89.3 and σ = 6.74

@lulu Thank you for the explanation. I see that there is a unique solution - but where did 0.663 come from? Here is the method I used to solve the problem.

I am not going to go through your link.  This is a routine linear system, it obviously has a unique solution.  Go through your method line by line to spot the error.

Next time -- or if you need to edit your question to clarify something -- use MathJax to display your equations as shown in http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. This time I did it for you.

You are experiencing the phenomenon called catastrophic cancellation.
The number $15.9$ has three significant digits,
but when you subtract it from $16$,
$$  16 - 15.9 = 0.1, $$
you are left with only one significant digit.
That would be fine if $\mu$ were exactly $15.9$. But it isn't. It's slightly smaller.
If you were to compute and use a more accurate value of $\mu$ before you attempted to compute $\sigma$, you would get a more accurate answer.
As it is, you get an answer that is accurate to one significant digit:
$0.663$ rounds to $0.7$.
(This is actually very lucky; when your only significant digit in one step of a computation is the digit $1$ you really have room for a large percentage error in your final results.)
If you don't want to work with more digits of $\mu$, try computing $\sigma$ first instead.

Why this is called "catastrophic cancellation":
The "cancellation" occurs when you subtract $15.9$ from $16$, and the "catastrophe" is that you lose almost all precision in your results.

By the way, the numbers $0.1509$ and $1.554$ are rounded down when they should be rounded up (assuming it is OK to use four significant digits here).
Also, when I put $\mu=15.9$ in $\dfrac{17−μ}{σ} = 1.554$
the result is $\sigma = 0.708$; I don't see you you got $\sigma = 0.712$.
